# XIAOMI MI4W with android 6.0.1 not set SMS_READ permission by programmatically

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm setting up permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

But unfortunatly I can't get SMS permissin, after I setted up application, I should go to security property of smartphone and set it by myself. What the reason, is it reason of MI restrictions or I must set somthing else in 6 version of Android. This worked on previos version on this smartphone.

Comment: You need runtime permission.

Comment: Starting from 6, you need to explicitly request some permissions: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

This library can simplify it a bit: https://github.com/tajchert/Nammu

Comment: Thx  I'll see ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Android marshmallow you need to give run time permission.
Add below given code in your launch activity onCreate() method.

```
String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS;
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    permissionList.add(permission);

    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), permission)){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{permission}), SMS_PERMISSION);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I ask both permission RESEVE_SMS & READ_SMS or enought RECEIVE ?

Comment: all the runtime permission you need to add in permission list one by one